# sequelize.js - Find by id and return result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a function,

```
var findUserDevice = function(userDeviceId){

    var device = db.DeviceUser.find({
        where: {
            id: userDeviceId
        }
    }).then(function(device) {
        if (!device) {
            return 'not find';
        }
        return device.dataValues;
    });
};
```

but this function does not return anything...

```
var UserDevice = findUserDevice(req.body.deviceUserId);
console.log(UserDevice);// undefined
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The operation you are trying to do is `async`, which means that you need to use a callback. Since `sequelize` is build on top of Promises, you should actually write your code like this :

```
var findUserDevice = function(userDeviceId){
    // return the promise itself
    return db.DeviceUser.find({
        where: {
           id: userDeviceId
        }
     }).then(function(device) {
        if (!device) {
            return 'not find';
        }
        return device.dataValues;
     });
};
```

And later use it like :

```
findUserDevice(req.body.deviceUserId).then( function(UserDevice) {
   console.log(UserDevice);
});
```

Comment: A note on Promises from the Sequelize documentation: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html#promises

Answer (score 14):

It's 2020, `async` & `await` are becoming more popular. You can change your code to:

```js
const findUserDevice = async function (userDeviceId) {
  const device = await db.DeviceUser.findOne({
    where: {
      id: userDeviceId
    }
  });
  if (device === null) {
    return 'device not found';
  }
  return device.dataValues;
};

 (async () => {
    // ...
    const UserDevice = await findUserDevice(req.body.deviceUserId);
    console.log(UserDevice);
    // ...
  })()
```

IMHO, the code above is way more readable.

Answer (score 9):

If you are getting undefined instead of 'not find' on the console, it means your function is returning a value. The problem might be dataValues is actually undefined. You need to check for the content of `device`.

Hint: Try returning just `device` or `device.id`

PS. If you want to do the search based on id, should go for `findById()` function of your model.

```
var device = db.DeviceUser.findById(userDeviceId).then(function(device) {
  if (!device) {
    return 'not find';
  }
  return device.dataValues;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This function received params id, this worker for me:

```
const  { customer }  = require('../models');

const get = async function(req, res){
    let id = req.params.id;

    [err, singleCustomer] = await to(customer.findByPk(id, { raw : true }));

    return ReS(res, { message :'Obtener cliente: : ', data : JSON.stringify(singleCustomer) });
}
```